# Why it must run genymotion by root in KDE desktop

Tags: linux, qt, segmentation-fault, genymotion

with Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0, KDE4.

I downloaded and installed the file genymotion-2.2.2_x86.bin. When I run the executable file genymotion it came out follows in ~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log.

```
[Genymotion] [Fatal] Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40806) with this library (version 0x40804)
```

So I had googled it arround. Delete all the libraries which name with "libQt*so*" where are in the installed path. Then run genymotion in shell and came out segmentation fault.

```
"dmesg |tail" said:
genymotion[16407]: segfault at 0 ip   (null) sp bfd9a46c error 14 in genymotion[8048000+179000]
```

But I run it with sudo and the genymotion started successfully. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
#apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev
```

2 - (Re)Moving the Qt libs inside the Genymotion installation directory

```
mkdir QtLibs && mv *Qt*.so* QtLibs
```

This last command will make Genymotion use the system's Qt libs.Hope this works for you.

Comment: I had made Genymotion use the Qt libs in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ at the very start. Always it went wrong.

Comment: @Ginhing your Qtlibs libary are new and latest version of Genymotion use old version and that Incompatible. i'm use this way and can be successfull run Genymotion

Answer (score 3):

From the official FAQ (https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#Qt-libraries)
"When starting Genymotion on Linux, why does an error message state that Qt library versions are incompatible?

Under Linux, when starting Genymotion, you may read the following error message: [Genymotion] [Fatal] Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version XXXXXXX) with this library (version XXXXXXX)

Indeed, Genymotion provides its own Qt library files. Those files may be incompatible with the version of libraries that already exist on your system. To solve this issue, you can remove Genymotion Qt library files so that the application uses the ones of your system.

To remove Genymotion Qt library files, in the Genymotion directory, run the following command: rm libQt*"

So, just delete this files from genymotion directory by provided command (rm libQt*) or manually.

Comment: This solved my problem after upgrading Ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. Deleting the libQ* libraries, as mentioned everywhere on the Internet, did not help since I would get a segmentation fault. Both, genymotion 2.4.0 and 2.5.0, had the same issue.

It worked when running as root or via ssh on local machine, either as root or normal user. 
So I suspected some environmental variable. 
First I've identified the difference between the two environments and started unseting the environmental variables until I found it: SESSION_MANAGER

If you are using bash try:

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
```

before running genymotion.